# Can MariaDB return incomplete data?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-connector, mariadb-10.5

I am using MySQL Connector to connect to a MariaDB server.

A function in my program periodically retrieves all entries in a table (with a `select * from ...` without any `where`s, `limit`s, etc.).

After it gets the data, it checks if these rows (using an auto-incremented id) are already present in its memory, and if not it adds them. But if a row does not exist in the retrieved list but presents in the memory-list, then that row must be deleted from memory.

Deleting that row from memory is not the only thing that's gonna happen. It also deletes a bunch of other tables/files linked to that row. So, if the connector somehow fails, does not retrieve the full list, and does not report this, then I'll get into trouble.

It might be a tad stupid question but I couldn't make sure if I needed any additional safety measures.

Comment: why not using a datetime column and retive all rows that are newer than the last retrival?

Comment: It may be that you could do what you're looking to do with a trigger ON DELETE on your table to delete the associated records on other tables. It would then then happen straight away without running extra code. It should be more reliable.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] where this is true: "Deleting that row from memory is not the only thing that's gonna happen. It also deletes a bunch of other tables/files linked to that row." ?  (How does deleting from memory, also delete data from tables/files linked to that row ?, mayb you should not have a trigger on that memory table ?